# How to correctly use str_replace in php to replace <numeric_*> fields in string?

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I'm having trouble replacing the numeric_ * elements of the xml file below.

I'm working with Spatie's array-to-xml library, which returns the elements of an array in xml format. Unfortunately I need to remove the `<numeric _ *>` and replace it with `<singlenews>` but I'm having problems ...

This is the PHP side code:

```
public function exportNews(){
    $news = News::all()->toArray();
    $result = ArrayToXml::convert(['__numeric' => $news]);
    return response($result)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
}
```

And this is the XML file that is returned:

```
<root>
<numeric_0>
<id>14</id>
<created_at>2019-08-25 19:19:07</created_at>
<updated_at>2019-08-25 20:02:46</updated_at>
<title>Lorem ipsum</title>
<body>imbardata</body>
<abstract>fondamentale</abstract>
<file_url>
foo
</file_url>
<author_name/>
</numeric_0>
<numeric_1>
<id>15</id>
<created_at>2019-10-01 22:14:55</created_at>
<updated_at>2019-10-01 22:14:55</updated_at>
<title>132</title>
<body>132</body>
<abstract>132</abstract>
<file_url>
foo
</file_url>
<author_name>Boris</author_name>
</numeric_1>
<numeric_2>
<id>16</id>
<created_at>2019-10-01 22:15:18</created_at>
<updated_at>2019-10-01 22:15:18</updated_at>
<title>123456</title>
<body>123</body>
<abstract>propva</abstract>
<file_url>
foo
</file_url>
<author_name>Boris</author_name>
</numeric_2>
</root>
```

I would be really grateful if someone could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just replace it like `str_replace` you can use:

```php
preg_replace("/numeric.*[0-9+]/", 'traki', $your_xml_string);
```

Where First paramter is regex, Second is string to replace with and third is string to replace

```
public function exportNews(){
    $news = News::all()->toArray();
    $result = ArrayToXml::convert(['__numeric' => $news]);

    $result = preg_replace("/numeric.*[0-9+]/", 'traki', $result);
    return response($result)
        ->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
}
```

Comment: Thanks!I just had to edit a bit:
`code`
public function exportNews(){
        $news = News::all()->toArray();
        //return $societies;
        $result = ArrayToXml::convert(['__numeric' => $news]);
        $result = preg_replace("/<numeric_[0-9+]>/", '<traki>', $result);
        $result = preg_replace("/<\/numeric_[0-9+]>/", '</traki>', $result);
        return response($result)
            ->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    }
`code`